# Post the following data using axios with help of picture

Tags: reactjs, react-native, post, axios, postman

With the help of this image I wish to construct an api call using axios post. While I am trying to get the data I'm facing error although the api is hitting the backend.

This is my code:

```
login = async() => {
let params = {
      email: "abc@gmail.com",
      password: "12342346667"
    }

let res0 = await axios.post('https://example.com/authentication/api/Login', params)
      .catch((error) => console.log('error', error));
}
```

Postman post method:

[image: Postman post method]

I am new to React.

Answer (score 0):

Try this way

```
axios.post('https://example.com/authentication/api/Login', {
    email: "abc@gmail.com",
    password: "12342346667"
  })
  .then(function response) {
    console.log(response);
  })
  .catch(function (error) {
    console.log(error);
  });
```